# Dynamically Populate one column values from another columns of same table

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra and I am trying to solve a use case where I need to populate one column values which is of JSON type from two of the columns data.

Existing column :

```
access_validity : 12345
refresh_validity : 45678
```

New Column :

```
{
"json_access_validity" : access_validity,
"json_refresh_validity" : refresh_validity
}
```

New Column value which if of JSON type, Its attributes are populated fromn another column's values.

Comment: do you need this once for existing data, or this should happen when you insert/update data?

Comment: I need this for existing data. rows are already populated and I am trying to update it @AlexOtt I am trying to populate new column's json with the help of two existing columns values.

Comment: @AlexOtt Could you please suggest any approach here.